# How do I hide the div that is encapsulating a component from an onClick inside the encapsulated component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I currently have the following code where I display a card inside a react-grid-layout div to make it resizable:

```
const Dashboard = () => {

  const [showCard, setShowCard] = React.useState(true)
  const closeCard = () => setShowCard(false)

  return (
    <div style = {{padding: "2%"}} >
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
        className = "layout"
        cols = {{ lg: 4, md: 2, sm: 1, xs: 1, xxs: 1 }}
        breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
        rowHeight = {150}
        layouts={layouts}
      >
        { showCard ? <div key="a" data-grid={{x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 4, minW: 1, minH: 4, maxW: 4, maxH: 4}}>
          <PortfolioAssets onClose={closeCard} />
        </div> : null }
      </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

onClose is called inside the encapsulated component, PortfolioAssets onClick of a button:

```
<IconButton 
  onClick = {props.onClose}
>
    <CloseIcon />
</IconButton>
```

I only want this div to close when the X button is clicked (IconButton), and the rest of the page be untouched:

```
{ showCard ? <div key="a" data-grid={{x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 4, minW: 1, minH: 4, maxW: 4, maxH: 4}}>
          <PortfolioAssets onClose={closeCard} />
        </div> : null }
```

The problem is, whenever I click the IconButton, it closes out every component and div on the entire page. Every div and card on the page closes out and it only shows the background color. I've tried several different ways, even with using a constructor, and it still didn't work. I'm not sure what else to try.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors logged in your console btw?

Comment: if there are multiple `<IconButton />` in `<PortfolioAssets />`, they will all be removed as the rendering of `<PortfolioAssets />` is based on `showCard`, and all `<IconButton />` have the same click handler which is setting `showCard` to `false`

Comment: Yes, `Warning: Failed prop type: Cannot read property 'key' of null
    in ReactGridLayout (created by ResponsiveReactGridLayout)` , `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null
    at utils.js:121` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of null
    at utils.js:121`

Comment: There is only 1 IconButton inside PortfolioAssets

Comment: I guess it's expecting a child with `key="a"` based on your `layouts`; what if you replace the `null` with `<div key="a"></div>`?

Comment: That returns the div I am trying to hide without the card, however, I tried entering <div key="b"></div> and it correctly deleted the entire div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When showCard is false you return a null child to ResponsiveReactGridLayout component and it appears that the component tries to read key attribute of children without checking if they are null. It seems there is an open issue for that: https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/577

A work around is to return a dummy component with a dummy key instead of null.

```
showCard ? <div key="a" data-grid={{x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 4, minW: 1, minH: 4, maxW: 4, maxH: 4}}> : <div key="dummy"/>
```